# Prevent threads from same or different session to execute same record twice

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, thread-safety

My project uses Hibernate, Spring, Executor framework and Quartz. I am trying to write a method that should not execute same record twice by a thread in same or different session. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Session 1:

```
T1 (2) 
T2 (15)
T3 (2) // should not execute as already executed by previous thread
```

Session 2:

```
T1 (14)
T2 (2) // should not execute as executed in different session
T3 (10)
```

I do not have control over the records that come in for execution. I need to make sure in my code that duplicate records dont get executed more than once.

Right now I am planning to have a status table in DB and keep track of already executed or currently executing records. Is there any better approach to accomplish this?

(Q1) Is there a way to get status of a thread (may be using callable/future) form different sessions?

(Q2) Can I share a lock between threads of different sessions? I know a way I can do it via application level context (Is it the only way?)

Thank you!

Comment: So to solve this I used a DB table. My code locks the row while a thread is working on it and then release the lock when thread is done with it. I have a STATUs column in that table to track not started, in process and completed tasks. Seems to be working fine. Will update if I find any concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AtomicBoolean executed = new AtomicBoolean(false);`as a guard, with

```
if(!executed.getAndSet(true)) {
    // proceed
}
```

Reason for yourself that this is a threadsafe, lock-free pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As you cited Spring, any spring singleton bean can contain objects than can be used (or can be used itself) for global synchronization. You simply inject it in any bean where you need such synchronization.

That is true as long as your application executes on a single tomcat on a single machine. If you are using (or plan to use) load balancing on multiple servers, you can only rely on database locks.

It is allways safe to store track of updated records on database, as you can do it in the same transaction where your treated the record. So consistency is garanteed even in worst case conditions such as hardware falling down, power outage etc.

If you have less requirements and only want to ensure consistency across a single run of the application on a single server, you can use a singleton bean with synchronized methods.